# cast/parse HTMLDocument to HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following function:

```
function append(htmlString,parentElem){
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var childElem = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
  parentElem.appendChild(childElem);
}
```

This function gets an html string and parent element. I am parsing the html string using DOMParser. When I am trying to append the `childElem` to `parentElem`, there is an error.

After googling I found that `appendChild` function expects `HTMLElement`.
`childElem` is instance of `HTMLDocument`.

How can I convert/cast/parse the `childElem` to `HTMLElement`?

Answer (score 2):

> how can i convert/cast/parse the childElem to HTMLElement

*(See the big **however** below...)*

You don't want to. Instead, append its `documentElement`, or more likely the `childNodes` of its `body` element:

```
function append(htmlString,parentElem){
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
  parentElem.appendChild(doc.documentElement);
}
```

```js
function append(htmlString, parentElem) {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
  parentElem.appendChild(doc.documentElement);
}
append("<span>New stuff added via <code>append</code></span>", document.getElementById("target"));
```

```html
<div id="target">Stuff already in the target element.</div>
```

Note how it's offset, because we've actually ended up appending a duplicate `body` element.

So instead, we do the child nodes:

```
function append(htmlString,parentElem){
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
  var nextNode;
  for (var node = doc.documentElement.firstChild; node; node = nextNode) {
      nextNode = node.nextSibling;
      parentElem.appendChild(node);
  }
}
```

```js
function append(htmlString,parentElem){
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
  var nextNode;
  for (var node = doc.body.firstChild; node; node = nextNode) {
      nextNode = node.nextSibling;
      parentElem.appendChild(node);
  }
}
append("<span>New stuff added via <code>append</code></span>", document.getElementById("target"));
```

```html
<div id="target">Stuff already in the target element.</div>
```

**However**, there's a built-in method on modern browsers that will do this work for you called [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```
function append(htmlString,parentElem){
    parentElem.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", htmlString);
}
```

```js
function append(htmlString,parentElem){
    parentElem.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", htmlString);
}
append("<span>New stuff added via <code>append</code></span>", document.getElementById("target"));
```

```html
<div id="target">Stuff already in the target element.</div>
```